# Does Prokka or gff3 change the sequence / subject ID of fasta files?

Tags: fasta, gff3, sequence-analysis

I used prokka to create a database for some fasta files but I noticed a strange difference between the prokka and fasta files. Normally the seqid for the gff3 output for prokka has seqid's that match the sequence id's of the fasta files. The files I just produced with prokka have a different seqid than my fasta files. My fasta files look like this

```
>NODE_108_length_645_cov_0.679537_ID_215
```

However the prokka output gff3 file for the same fasta file uses a seqid like this

```
gnl|X|JHIOGLGG_28
```

What would cause this difference? And do the last digits still correlate to the same seqid's even though the string before it has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prokka is an annotation tool. It takes your contigs file with fasta headers `>NODE_108...`and searchs for ORFs and their putative functions. Prokka produces submission ready output, the new fasta headers you see `>JHIOGLGG_28...`are locus tags and gene description from the annotation and are not related to contig node data. Please see the [github information page](https://github.com/tseemann/prokka#output-files) for more info.